# What is the rule of firebase realtime database that shows users all its data with security

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

What is the rule of firebase realtime database that shows users all its data with security

```
{ "rules": { ".read": "auth != true", ".write": "auth != true" } }
```

**This rule is not provide user security**

Comment: See the Firebase documentation on [implementing content-only access in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#the_auth_variable) you need to use the `uid` property of the `auth` variable in a Security Rule to identify the user.

**But the exact rule depends on your data model.**

The below example, copied/pasted from the documentation (cf. above link), is based on the following data model: a `users` node contains, for each user, a sub-node with an id equivalent to the user `uid`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's up to you to adapt it to your specific data model.

---

You may be interested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59408846/3371862) which explains that, in certain cases, relying on the fact a user is authenticated is not sufficient. Again it depends on your specific case.