# Can you send sign-up link email with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

We are using Firebase on our project and we want only users who recieved an email invitation to be able to access register page and create a profile afterwards.
Can you do that using firebase?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Firebase Authentication to allow only users you've invited to sign up. When the email+password provider is enabled, anyone can call the API and register.

What you *can* do though is have a list of the invited email addresses in an online database somewhere (such as Firebase's Realtime Database of Firestore) and check against that list whether a user is **authorized** after they have signed in.

For an example of how to limit access to the database to specific users, have a look at:

- for Realtime Database: [How do I lock down Firebase Database to any user from a specific (email) domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943350/how-do-i-lock-down-firebase-database-to-any-user-from-a-specific-email-domain/38019847#38019847)
- for Firestore: [Restrict Firestore gmail sign in to specific domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985612/restrict-firestore-gmail-sign-in-to-specific-domain/51850335#51850335)