# Firebase permissions based on user's role

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

In my application I am supposed to have **three** kinds of roles:

- Store: Can do whatever kind of **reads** and **writes** on anything bellow their owned key;
- Customers: Can create their **chat** keys only underneath their designated store; Once a chat is created they can only push to the **message** child, on their own chats;
- Attendants: Can only update **chats** which are designated to them, and insert under their **messages** tag.

The database is something similar to:

```
"$store_id": {
    "owner": STORE_ID,
    "chats": {
        ...
        "$chat_id": {
            "owner": COSTUMER,
            "attendant": ATTENDANT,
            "messages": {
                "$message_id": {
                    "owner": CUSTOMER_ID
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how I can achieve this behavior because:

1. If a permission is applied to a top level node, their children can't override it;
2. If someone crack into the database with valid credentials *(i.e.: customers')*, they can assume whatever role they want;

How this kind of issue is managed in **Firebase**?

Comment: Did you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815229/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-registrations-in-firebase/21834842#21834842

Comment: Yes. I solved the role's problem. But I still stuck on the hierarchy stuff.

Comment: You could try to break out your `chats/$chat_id/messages` structure to the root, so it would be `/chatMessages/$chat_id`, that way you don't have to worry about nesting