# is there a way in firebase to grant access keys or restrict who can register?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I want to create something like invitations, not sure if its possible with firebase.

I don't want just anyone to be able to register and sign in to the app.

how can I control who can register?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815229/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-registrations-in-firebase

Comment: I saw that, however I don't want to make everyone an admin, I will have admins, I just want all the other accounts to be invitation only

Answer (score 3):

Actually with Firebase you cannot prevent someone to register as a user of your app as long as you offer a form to register, so you will have to prevent read/write from accounts you don't authorize (i.e. without invitations) through database rules.

In addition you could clean up the undesired accounts through a CloudFunction that run every hour/day/...

Comment: It's indeed not directly possible. But I saw this answer today, which is an interesting way to limit the scope of what can be one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162111/how-to-prevent-new-user-registration-on-firebase