# How to restrict user to use specific domain to sign up my app using firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing an app for my university using Ionic 2 and Firebase. So, the problem is how to restrict user from signing up unless they're using specific domain eg.(@ukm.edu.my)? It's for my university, I don't want anyone else to use this app. So, anyone without that specific email domain can't sign up for my app.

From what I've read, Firebase database rules only affect authorization. So, how to setup rules for authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with what Firebase provides.

You can only restrict access to the database adding a rule stating that users with email in a specific domain can access it.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.token.email.endsWith('@example.com')",
    ".write": "auth.token.email.endsWith('@example.com')",
  }
}
```

Comment: So, there's no other way I can prevent other people from signing up my apps if I am using firebase?

Comment: You can't limit people from signing in with Firebase Authentication. But you can prevent them from accessing data they're not authorized for.

Comment: See some of these previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17728534/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21834842/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064712/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357717/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43547921/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019847/209103

Comment: Thank you  @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I want the same rule in my app sign-up but Firebase updated some syntax of rule with `match` keyword do you have any idea how to write above rule in latest firebase rules syntax?